# android VM won't let us allocate 10458756 bytes Error on setBackgroundResource of Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, imagebutton

I simply want to change Image of my button on click. Just button which looks like `"clicked"` and `"not clicked"`
My button Image size is not big:164 KB

My code worked fine with `android version 2.3.3`
on latest versions I started to get the Errors

I have read a lot of stuff in Internet and still can't find an answer.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)){
                //Do whatever you want after press                  
                center_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)){             
                //Do whatever you want during press
                //((BitmapDrawable)center_button.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
                center_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clicked);
                count++;
            }
            return false;
```

I have tried all following things and it didn't help:

1. `((BitmapDrawable)center_button.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();` before changing the image
2. changing to Imagebutton
3. adding destroy method with recycle

Errors:

```
11-11 20:09:18.305: D/dalvikvm(932): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 19K, 52% free 2605K/5379K, external 12929K/14977K, paused 43ms
11-11 20:09:18.625: D/dalvikvm(932): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 10K, 52% free 2594K/5379K, external 17468K/19516K, paused 29ms
11-11 20:09:18.645: E/dalvikvm-heap(932): 10458756-byte external allocation too large for this process.
11-11 20:09:18.675: E/GraphicsJNI(932): VM won't let us allocate 10458756 bytes
11-11 20:09:18.675: D/dalvikvm(932): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 52% free 2594K/5379K, external 17468K/19516K, paused 17ms
11-11 20:09:18.675: D/AndroidRuntime(932): Shutting down VM
11-11 20:09:18.675: W/dalvikvm(932): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.lyuhanan.button.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:93)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-11 20:09:18.695: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 20:09:30.735: I/Process(932): Sending signal. PID: 932 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please check the image dimension. I think its compressed size is 164K. It may be 10MB uncompressed...

Comment: Agreed. 164KB is **huge** for a button background. To put it in perspective, the stock button background images (nine-patch PNG files) are under 2K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the VM number in Android Emulator from 32 to 320 and it is working now. 
Still I don't understand why it is failed before.